# Iterate vertically on an image to get its pixel indexes

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate over the pixels in an image, but rather vertically instead of the normal horizontal way. Here is an example of a small-sized image I might have (I have images where the size is in the hundreds):

```
"""
Note: X represents pixels
Sample Image (3 x 4):

X X X X
X X X X
X X X X
"""
```

Clearly, to iterate over this image horizontally, it is easy to do so, as I have done here:

```
import itertools

width = range(3)
height = range(4)

print("Pixel positions:")
for pixel in itertools.product(width, height):
    print(*pixel)
```

**Output:**

```
Pixel positions:
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
1 0
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 0
2 1
2 2
2 3
```

These are the index positions of the pixels in the image (assume it as a large 2D list of pixels) but iterated horizontally. I want to be able to do the same but *vertically*. Is there an itertools function that allows me to do the same but column-wise? Here are the indexes for this sample image:

```
Column-wise:
0 0
1 0
2 0
0 1
1 1
2 1
0 2
1 2
2 2
0 3
1 3
2 3
```

I have attempted to reverse the positions with `print(*pixel[::-1])`, however, this results in certain index positions that are out of range such as the last one from `2 3` to `3 2`. `3 2` is not valid as there aren't 3 rows (0, 1, 2 only). The same goes for other positions as well.

I would like a solution *without* the use of non-built-in libraries. Itertools is fine as I am using it for something else in my program.

Comment: Why not a double `for` loop? Do do you really need a one-line solution?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
width = range(3)
height = range(4)

print("Pixel positions:")
for x in height:
    for y in width:
        print(y, x)
```

**Output:**

```
Pixel positions:
0 0
1 0
2 0
0 1
1 1
2 1
0 2
1 2
2 2
0 3
1 3
2 3
```

To iterate horizontally just swap the two for-loops:

```
width = range(3)
height = range(4)

print("Pixel positions:")
for y in width:
    for x in height:
        print(y, x)
```

**Performance comparison:**

```
$ python -m timeit -n 100 '
width = range(1000)
height = range(1000)

for pixel in ((x, y) for y in height for x in width):
    pass
'
100 loops, best of 3: 104 msec per loop
```

Nested for-loop is about **8x** faster:

```
$ python -m timeit -n 100 '
width = range(1000)
height = range(1000)

for y in width:
    for x in height:
        pass
'
100 loops, best of 3: 12.7 msec per loop
```

When also creating a tuple containing the result coordinates, the code is still **2x** faster. But it is questionable if creating a tuple containing the coordinates is required for the task at hand.

```
$ python -m timeit -n 100 '
width = range(1000)
height = range(1000)

for y in width:
    for x in height:
        (x, y)
'
100 loops, best of 3: 52.5 msec per loop
```

Comment: I am using images that are like 1MB in size. Could using nested for loops affect efficiency

Comment: In any case you are visiting all width x height pixels once. The performance should be roughly the same. `itertools.product` also iterates over width x height, it just hides it from you.

Comment: I see, but I have used a generator in conjunction with the other method and it is somewhat faster than both. Thank you anyways.

Comment: Your comparison are a bit unfair: first code creates tuples  `(x, y)` while the second code does not. Replacing the `pass` in the second code with `(x, y)` brings the two times closer. Your code still wins, but with a smaller advantage.

Comment: @rodrigo you are right, the comparison is unfair. But it is questionable if creating a tuple is actually required for the task. Anyhow, I added a third performance test to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, `itertools.product(width, height)` is equal to:

```
((x, y) for x in width for y in height)
```

If you want to iterate column-wise, just swap the inner loops:

```
for pixel in ((x, y) for y in height for x in width):
    print(*pixel)

0 0
1 0
2 0
0 1
1 1
2 1
0 2
1 2
2 2
0 3
1 3
2 3
```

Comment: Thanks, this has worked in my favour and also it is more efficient than nested for loops.

Comment: @SurajKothari see the performance comparison in my answer, a nested for-loop is about **8x** faster